# Angular Validation Question concerning Reactive Forms

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

Hi and thank you for taking a moment.I have a  control for which I would like to validate that there is at least 1 item in the box. I believe I need to write a customvalidator for this, as this is different from making sure something is selected in the box (Is that true? I don't think the built in validators of required, min, or minlength will work here. ...am I wrong ? ) My validator code is below . I was told that I most likely need it to return a ValidatorFn. Any help with this would be most appreciated as I have tried a number of things. --Jason

```html
//Don't believe control.get.length === 0  is correct , keeps coming back as 1
CheckThatSelectedCountiesHasValues(): ValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } => {
      return control.get.length === 0 ? { 'needcounties': true } : null
    };
  }
```

```html
//component code to attach the validator to the control
createFormControls() {
    this.lstcountiesselected = new FormControl('',    Validators.compose([this.customValidator.CheckThatSelectedCountiesHasValues()]));
  }
```

```html
  //html validator message
  <span *ngIf="lstcountiesselected.errors">
        <span *ngIf="registerFormControl.lstcountiesselected.errors?.needcounties">
          <p class="hasErrorExpl">***County is required***</p>
        </span>
  </span>
```

Comment: Did you try the required validator? If your value is "false-y" when empty, I think it will work.

Comment: to do proper validation it would be nice to know what kind of control u r using?